# Electron version update breaks css

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, electron, electron-builder

I have built a desktop application using Electron js version 4.0.1
But when now I'm updating the version, it somehow breaking mostly the CSS(scroll behavior). Does anyone know how to fix this?
Current version : 4.0.1
Updated version : 11.0.0
The reason might be because of the new engines, but not aware of the correct reason and a workaround for this.

Comment: The current version of Electron is 11.something v5.0.0 is from almost two years ago, are you sure that's the package you're updating?

Comment: @ZacAnger I have updated it to 11 and it is still breaking the scroll behaviour

Comment: Maybe it would help if you add your code. "CSS scroll behaviour" can be anything. The differences between 4 and 11 are of course enormous, but CSS is not a part of electron framework. So maybe it has to do something with an outdated CSS and an updated Chromium in 11.